# Using Powershell to Query if any network folders contain a specific security group

Tags: powershell

Hi I am trying to devise a way to create a script that will allow me to enter a security group and see if any of our Directories actually use it. I have a feeling we have some orphaned groups, and there is a lot of cleanup to be done in our AD environment.

I am familiar with the commands but creating scripts is not my thing.

1. connect azuread
2. set NT path
3. create $var sec group name
4. get-adgroup? and some kind of foreach command find $var
5. Format-list and output to excel

Does that seem remotely correct?
Thanks
Jon

get-acl "\company path" | Format-List

Shows me what a particular folder has which is great. But i want to search recursively and also be able to input the group to query.

Thanks

Comment: Is the computer(s) you want to run the script on a member of an on-premise AD forest? If yes, what would be the purpose of connecting to azure AD?

Comment: Working from home using a vpn. Is it still required? I 100 percent could be wrong.

Comment: Is _what_ still required? You didn't answer my question, check domain join status with `dsregcmd /status |Select-String '[dn]Joined'` :)